# Ubuntu Phone BQ Aquaris E4.5 still need Android OS?

Tags: phone

I would like to have a phone that does not use Android at all. But i got suspicious when i saw in the BQ shop that appears a note saying that runs on Android.

http://store.bqreaders.com/en/smartphones/aquaris-e4-5

Can anyone clarify me? Does it have or not Android? And if it has, it is possible to remove it and only have the Ubuntu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the BQ phones use Android except for 1 -limited- version that has Ubuntu Touch on it. That is not the one you are looking at: the one with Ubuntu on it is called Bq [Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition](http://www.bq.com/gb/ubuntu.html) and you can not order it normally; you have to wait for a flash sale.